# How to read data from bigtable in google data proc

Tags: hbase, bigtable, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-bigtable

I am tring to read data from Bigtable in Google cloud data proc.
Below code i am using to read data from Bigdtable.

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).create();
        options.setRunner(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.class);
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.setFilter(new FirstKeyOnlyFilter());
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
        p.apply(Read.from(CloudBigtableIO.read(new CloudBigtableScanConfiguration.Builder()
                .withProjectId("xxxxxxxx").withZoneId("xxxxxxx")
                .withClusterId("xxxxxx").withTableId("xxxxx").withScan(scan).build())))
                .apply(ParDo.named("Reading data from big table").of(new DoFn<Result, Mutation>() {

                    @Override
                    public void processElement(DoFn<Result, Mutation>.ProcessContext arg0) throws Exception {

                        System.out.println("Inside printing");
                        if (arg0==null)
                        {
                            System.out.println("arg0 is null");
                        } else
                        {

                            System.out.println("arg0 is not null");
                            System.out.println(arg0.element());
                        }

                    }

                }));

        p.run();
```

Whenever i am calling **arg0.element()** in my method i am getting below error.

```
2017-03-21T12:29:28.884Z: Error:   (deec5a839a59cbca): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12338
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue.keyToString(KeyValue.java:1231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue.keyToString(KeyValue.java:1190)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.hbase.adapters.read.RowCell.toString(RowCell.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result.toString(Result.java:804)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
    at com.slb.StarterPipeline$2.processElement(StarterPipeline.java:102)
```

Can anyone let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately a [known issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/1227).  We fixed the underlying implementation, and we're hoping to release a new version of our client in the next week or so.  I would suggest changing this line:

> `System.out.println(arg0.element());`

To something like:

> `System.out.println(Bytes.toStringBinary(arg0.element().getRow());`

Sorry for your troubles.